# VS2012 stops working after Win10 1607 update (anniversary update)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-10, auto-update

I´ve just updated my Windows 10 dev machine with the following update kit:

```
Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607
```

After that update, started automatically when I shut down Windows, I´m trying to open my VS2012 solutions and I´m getting the following error for all of my projects in all of my solutions:

```
Load Failed. The project requires user input. Reload the project for more information.
```

After choosing "Reload Project" I get the same error and on the output windows I get:

```
error  : Internal error occurred. Additional information: ''.
```

Seens that this Win10 update messed up with my development environment.

Does anyone had the same behaviour ? What can be done without a full reinstall ?

Comment: try to repair the VS2012 from control->panel->programs & features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update VS2012 ( Tools > Extension and updates... > Updates )
The Vs2012 Update 5 fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried the update 5 for VS 2012 and that did not solve the problem. What did solve the problem was removing  Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4025344)